# Flying from Stockholm to Paris via Istanbul with French National ID Card

Tags: customs-and-immigration, istanbul, turkish-airlines, french-citizens, stockholm

Since I won't have my French passport, I'll have to fly from Stockholm (ARN) to Paris (CDG) via Istanbul (IST) with my French National ID card.

I called the Swedish police and Turkish Airlines who said it should be fine, but they seemed confused by my question, I am not sure they understood it, and I'm not sure the staff (both at the boarding gate, and at police check) at Stockholm Arlanda airport will agree anyway.

Anyone with such experience at Arlanda airport, documented opinion, or advice? Thanks

Comment: Which kind of staff are you thinking about? The exit passport check is done by the Swedish police, whom you have already talked to, and the check-in and boarding agents work for the _airline_, whom you have _also_ talked to. I can't imagine you will be showing the ID to anyone who works for the _airport_.

Comment: Hello @HenningMakholm! Thanks for your comment, I edit my question with the following: I couldn't contact the Police staff at the airport (I was told they can't transfer me) nor the Turkish Airline staff at Arlanda (I think they are subcontracting there, so they don't even work for TK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be fine. With your French ID card (CNI), you can fly from Stockholm to Paris (as part of the Schengen).

Also, as a French national, you can also enter Turkey with the CNI :

http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa

So I think based on those two things, you should be fine with just the CNI.

Comment: Thanks @ar5975 
I had no problem traveling with my French ID card. I even got out at Istanbul airport and back in without any problem.

Comment: @Fehmi great. Good to hear. Hope you had a good trip :)