# Dual nationality - France<->Russia with ID card

Tags: france, covid-19, dual-nationality, borders, russia

I live, work and study in France. I have an internship opportunity in Russia in May. I have both nationalities.

Flights:

- France -> Russia (May)
- Russia -> France (August)

I have the following documents:

- Valid Russian "external" passport
- Valid French ID card (CNI)
- (expired French passport)

I'm confident that this is possible since reading [this thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96283/double-nationality-leaving-entering-europe-with-id-card). However, I'm not in the exact same situation (I'm French, not Greek), and it's a 3-year-old question.

Furthermore, I am worried about covid-19 restrictions. I may need to travel through Turkey before arriving in Russia. The flights would become:

- France -> Turkey -> Russia
- Russia -> Turkey -> France

I'm also confident this is possible thanks to [this thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124205/flying-from-stockholm-to-paris-via-istanbul-with-french-national-id-card) and this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_French_citizens) (states that Turkey accepts French citizens with an ID card and currently has no covid travel restrictions)

Questions are the following:

- Is a new French passport necessary for the flights I mentioned?
- Would it be a good idea to make one in case covid restrictions change before or during my internship?

Comment: Relying in this subject field on an almost-four-year old question and answer is a poor idea: travel rules change, and lately they've been changing a lot because of the pandemic. Even if permitted now, rules may change again between now and your travel dates. Do check carefully just before departure that the covid rules allow you to travel and transit as you wish; you may be required to present proof of a covid test, quarantine upon arrival, and not having been present in some countries some number of days before your travel.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica the EU requires EU and Schengen countries to accept national ID cards as proof of nationality for the purpose of the free movement directive, though not every covered country issues these cards.  They're therefore similar to, but more widely useful than, a US passport card (and Ireland's is even called a passport card).  Some other countries accept citizens of certain countries with ID cards in lieu of passports, which is why some EU citizens can use them to visit Turkey.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.